# How to check spelling right or wrong in textbox in HTML using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check spelling right or wrong in textbox in HTML using jQuery?

```
function test()
{
 document.querySelector("#editor").spellcheck = "true";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool library that i have used before.
http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/JavaScript_Spell_As_You_Type_Demo

It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use [jQuery Spellchecker](http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/). It looks pretty and it's corrections are non-disturbing.

It's also very useful in various situations and with great documentation.

---

#### Example (with textarea)

```
// Init the text spellchecker
var spellchecker = new $.SpellChecker('.textarea', {
  lang: 'en',
  parser: 'text',
  webservice: {
    path: '../webservices/php/SpellChecker.php',
    driver: 'google'
  },
  suggestBox: {
    position: 'above'
  },
  incorrectWords: {
    container: '#incorrect-word-list'
  }
});
 
// Bind spellchecker handler functions
spellchecker.on('check.success', function() {
  alert('There are no incorrectly spelt words.');
});
 
// Check the spelling when user clicks on button
$("#check-spelling-button").click(function(e){
  spellchecker.check();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting it to the String "true" (which is a true value) and to the String "false" (which is also a true value).

Use Booleans, not Strings. Get rid of the quotes.

```
document.querySelector("#editor").spellcheck = true;
```